# Ensuring latest version of website is displayed

Tags: html, caching, web, static, refresh

I have a static HTML site operational and I recently made quite extensive changes to it. However by default, browsers show the old version of the site unless the page is refreshed. I had a couple of my friends try to load the site as well and they had the same problem, but it sorted itself out after one refresh.

My question is how do I ensure the latest version of the site is displayed to visitors without them having to refresh the page?

Does this have something to do with the cache?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [cache-control](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html#cache-control) meta tag.